# How to do concurrent read & write on SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am creating a Windows Store application, which takes a lot of data from web service daily and then insert/update data to SQLite. So the user has to wait till the data is downloaded to SQLite database then he is redirected to other screen whcih shows that downloaded data in user friendly manner.

Is it possible to run the downloading & database operations in background and user can use the app ? I tried to combine the downloading & insertion operations & UI of showing the data in single page but I am getting error "database is locked". If my app is suspended, will database insertion/update & web service call work in background ?

PS : I am using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a number of inserts in a single transaction, like so

```
using (SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("[database path]"))
{
    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        db.Insert(MyClass);
    });
}
```

This should prevent database locking.